# Standalone tomcat 5.5 can't access other than on localhost

Tags: tomcat, http, localhost

Clean install of Tomcat 5.5.  I know it's older, but the webapp I am needing does not support newer versions.  I can access it just fine using localhost, but I can't get to it from a remote computer.  Sends a 404 error.  I am really new to this stuff, so if there is something stupid you would not even suggest, please do it anyway.  :)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `/path/to/tomcat/conf/server.xml` file and remove `address="127.0.0.1"` from `<Connector` tag:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

---

**EDIT**

```
  netstat -nao | findstr :80

  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3180
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3180
  TCP    74.208.231.23:80       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8005         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3180
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       3180
  TCP    [::]:8009              [::]:0                 LISTENING       3180
```

Pay attention to the last column of netstat output. There is a process (PID 4) listen on port 80. Stop all other processes listen on port 80 (Web Development Agent, Microsoft SQL Reporting, ...) and try again.

Comment: Here is my current connector tag:  <Connector port="80" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />

Comment: I added in protocol="HTTP/1.1", but that did not change anything.  Thanks for the sugesstion, though.

Comment: Port 80? Is there anything else listen on that port? Which OS are you running? You access from remote computer inside LAN? Please post the full content of `server.xml`?

Comment: The entire content is too big to post, and I don't see an attachments option.  Other than the change to port 80, and adding the protocol option, it's the generic server.xml.  It was my understanding that 80 was best to run as standalone.  OS is Win2K8 R2.  Server is hosted, not on LAN.  Looks like tomcat has 80 all to itself:                                                              Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 [tomcat5.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:110            u15728398:0            LISTENING

Comment: Corrected post:Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:25             u15728398:0            LISTENING
 [MESMTPC.EXE]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             u15728398:0            LISTENING
 [tomcat5.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:110            u15728398:0            LISTENING
 [MEPOPS.EXE]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            u15728398:0            LISTENING

Comment: You can copy `server.xml` content, paste to pastebin.com and insert link here. What the `netstat -nao | findstr :80` says? (You should edit the original post to append output to keep formatting)

Comment: also, I can't access it from it's own IP address, only localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: Here is the link in pasebin.  Thanks for the suggestion.  http://pastebin.com/GZ8LUGj0

Comment: here is that netstat result: http://pastebin.com/RMs8Ucuq

Comment: Sorry, could you please post the content of all the files in `conf/Catalina/localhost/` or run the command `egrep -lr 'allow="localhost"|allow="127\.0\.0\.1"' $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/` to find out all the files including `allow="127.0.0.1"` or `allow="localhost"`.

Comment: Here is host-manager.xml: http://pastebin.com/RqpmeTFg

Comment: here is manager.xml: http://pastebin.com/u9FMqcCQ

Comment: that's all the files

Comment: did a quick manual search for 'localhost' and 127.0.0.1 in the conf dir, but didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: Is there any firewall on this machine? Can you `telnet` from remote to port 80?

Comment: firewall is off, I will check telnet.

Comment: Pay attention to the last column of `netstat` output. There is a process (PID 4) listen on port 80. Change Tomcat port to 8080 for example and try again.

Comment: I have switched it back to 8080, still the same results. still does not work. here is new netstat. http://pastebin.com/z34q9WAm

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat? I don't see port 8080 open.

Comment: pretty sure I had already, but I just did it again.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means that listen on all interfaces. Go to [canyouseeme](http://canyouseeme.org/) to check for yourself.

Comment: it's showing 8080 as blocked...  Hmm I don't know why.

Comment: but 80 is fine.

Comment: _"blocked"_ means that it may have a firewall. If you cannot find out it, you can switch back to port 80 but **remember to stop all other processes listen on port 80 (Web Development Agent, Microsoft SQL Reporting, ...) before doing**.

Comment: So, I had to stop the 'Web Deployment Agent Service', and that finally freed up 80.  Switched tomcat back to 80, and everything is working fine and dandy!  Thank you so much for your help!