# Can only connect to Apache Tomcat with localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat, localhost

I can access my web application by going to http://localhost:8080/webapp, however, I cannot access it by using my local IP address.  As far as I know, I am using default configuration options.

This is also on Windows Server 2008 R2 and there is no firewall currently running.

Thanks.

Here is a link to the server.xml file: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1dad

Comment: Post your `server.xml` file.

Comment: I have edited my post with a link to my file.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/299102/standalone-tomcat-5-5-cant-access-other-than-on-localhost

Comment: Followed the suggestions in that post, but still having same problem.

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -nao | findstr :8080`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `address="[IP ADDRESS HERE]"` within the connector tag in the server.xml file, and it now works properly.